# Cannot connect to Remote SQL DB with Dreamfactory

Tags: mysql, rest

I am attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database using DreamFactory app.

This is what I am doing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSK1X.png

And this is the error I see in the Dreamfactory app log:

> [2014-06-14 09:47:53] app.ERROR: REST Exception #500 > Failed to
>   launch service "myservice": CDbConnection failed to open the DB
>   connection.
>   {"host":"myaddress","request_uri":"/rest/myapp","source_ip":"*.*.*.*","sapi_name":"apache2handler"}
>   [] [2014-06-14 09:47:53] app.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't
>   connect to MySQL server on '*.*.*.*' (111) [] []

I checked on my MySQL machine for any access attempts and I see none.
I think I configured something wrong in the Dreamfactory Admin screens.
Please help!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User has answered his own question. Had to enable incoming connections within his Amazon EC2 instance. Just a heads up to others having the same issue out there.

Thanks,
Mark